# Gaussian convolution of a multivariate Airy function

Tags: convolution, airy-functions

I need calculate the convolution

$$
Q(q, p) \equiv (\varphi_\vec{r}*W)(q, p)
$$

Of a Wigner function $W(q, p)$ on real phase space with a multinormal distribution $\varphi_\vec{r}(q, p)$, where we have

$$
W(q,p)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi} \,a^{1/3}} \,
\mathrm{e}^{\frac{6 a p + 1}{12 a^2}} \,
\mathrm{Ai} \left( \frac{a q^2 + p}{a^{1/3}} + \frac{1}{4 a^{4/3}} \right)
$$

$$
\varphi_\vec{r}(q, p)= \frac{1}{\pi} \mathrm{e}^{-(q^2 + p^2)}
$$

$$
\{q, p \} \in \mathbb{R} \; \mathrm{and} \; a>0 \,.
$$

I was hoping this could be done using the convolution theorem

$$
(\varphi_\vec{r}*W)(q, p) = \mathcal{F}^{-1} \left( \mathcal{F}(\varphi_\vec{r}) \cdot \mathcal{F}(W) \right)(q, p) \; ,
$$

but I struggle to find the Fourier transform of $\mathcal{F}(W)$.

**Context:** $W(q, p)$ is the Wigner quasiprobability distribution of a non-Gaussian quantum state. I need its Husimi Q-function $Q(q, p)$, which is a physically equivalent quasiprobability distribution and can be calculated by convolution of the Wigner function with a Gaussian.